# Xslt 1.0 format node and then sum

Tags: xslt

**How to format node and then sum those nodes?**

I am using sum function and then formatting.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/Item/Total),'&#163;#.00')"/>
```

But when I try to do like

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(format-number(/Item/Total,'&#163;#.00'))"/>
```

it is throwing me an error saying sum cannot be applied like that.

This is used to generate a report via C#

Comment: The sum function expects as input a node-set, whereas the format-number function returns a string. What's the precise error you get? Also, what are you trying to achieve exactly in the case of the second attempt? Are you sure you mean xslt 2? Both these functions are available in Microsoft's implementation which is (afaik) only version 1 (unfortunately).

Comment: @Marcus basically i want to convert these nodes to a formatted number (2 decimal place formatting and then compute the sum. The error is about the node set as you mentioned

Comment: @RohithNair "*i want to convert these nodes to a formatted number (2 decimal place formatting and then compute the sum.*" That makes no sense. Do you perhaps want to **round** the numbers before summing them?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes .. I thought format number will do so..i just need a rounding on those nodes before summing it up, and showing the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i just need a rounding on those nodes before summing it up

In XSLT 1.0, you have to do this in two steps. Given:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item id="1">
        <amount>1.996</amount>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <amount>2.495</amount>
    </item>
    <item id="3">
        <amount>10</amount>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="rounded-amounts">
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <amt>
                <xsl:value-of select="round(amount * 100) div 100" />
            </amt>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- final pass -->
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($rounded-amounts)/amt)" />
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>14.5</output>
```